# HTTPS URLs redirection in ProxySerlvlet

Tags: java, servlets

We are using proxy-1.0.2.jar in our application and need to POST xml payload to the redirected URL. When we do a redirect to HTTPS URL it's not working. But other HTTP or static IP address is working fine. Do we need to do any extra configuration for HTTPS URL in proxy filter?

Sample urls:

```
https url - https://abc.com/request/listing (not working)
http url - http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/request/listing (working)
```

In web.xml, we have the following entries:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>listingProxyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/proxy/listing</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>listingProxyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.woonoz.proxy.servlet.ProxyServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>target-url</param-name>
        <param-value>https://abc.com/request/listing</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution and posting here. it may helpful for others

I have used HTTP proxy servlet ver. 2.6 and it's working fine

http://www.servletsuite.com/servlets/httpproxy.htm

```
<servlet>
                <servlet-name>accertifyListingProxyServlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>com.jsos.httpproxy.HttpProxyServlet</servlet-class>
                <init-param>
                        <param-name>host</param-name>
                        <param-value>https://abc.com/order</param-value>
                </init-param>
                <init-param>
                        <param-name>headers</param-name>
                        <param-value>true</param-value>
                </init-param>
                <init-param>
                        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
                        <param-value>utf-8</param-value>
                </init-param>
        </servlet>
```

Regards,
Sourabh